# What is this white round plastic container called?

Tags: phrase-requests, image-identification

What do we call this type of round-shaped plastic container?
[image]

Comment: It is called a "plain pill bottle".  See, for example, [Plain Pill Bottle](https://www.featurepics.com/online/Plain-Pill-Bottle-Clip-Pathed-Pics203125.aspx)

Comment: Depends how big it is. The photo does not make that clear. Could be the size of a dustbin.

Comment: I would just say "bottle".  It may be used for something other than pills.

Comment: Also try [google image search](https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?site=search&image_url=https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsUt7.jpg) (you supply an image and it returns web sites that are 'like that' and you can see the text associated. It's hit or miss; those results are attended to the tamper proof part of the picture, not the bottles.

Answer (score 1):

In American English it is often called a "pill bottle" or "pill container" (even if it doesn't actually contain pills). Here is an image of a "pill bottle" [from an Indian e-commerce site](https://www.indiamart.com/proddetail/plastic-pill-bottle-15019099488.html):

[image]

And here is a stock image of a "pill bottle" [from iStock's U.S. site](https://www.istockphoto.com/photo/pill-bottle-gm177387418-20504499):

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry about the size of the pictures; I used this site's preferred method of including images but wasn't sure about how to reduce their size. If anyone can do so, feel free to edit them yourself or let me know how to do so.

Comment: Try using s or m at the end of the image name as [described on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189642/323179), like https://i.stack.imgur.com/CS2cqm.jpg .(I won't help you directly because I'm on mobile.)

Comment: @Laurel Perfect, thanks! (Perhaps we could add that to the [help pages](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)?)